# How can I convert a List<Map<String,dynamic> to a single variable in Dart?

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart, concatenation

var fruits = [{'apple':'5Kg'},{'orange':'1Kg'},{'Kiwi':'2Kg'}];

I want the output like:

String fruitBucket = "Apple:5kg,Orange:1Kg,Kiwi:2Kg;

Someone please advice. TIA

Comment: Could you explain your problem clearly?

Comment: I just have a List of Map and all I need is I want to put all elements from the list to a single String variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work:

```dart
void main() {
  var fruits = [{'apple':'5Kg'},{'orange':'1Kg'},{'Kiwi':'2Kg'}];
  var fruitsString = fruits.map((fruit) => '${fruit.entries.first.key}:${fruit.entries.first.value}').join(',');
  print(fruitsString);
}
```

Though if I were you I would re-consider your data format to something like:

```dart
var fruits = [{'name': 'apple', 'amount': '5'}, ....];
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much!